# Spring Repository integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

I have a java project with spring framework. I have 4.3.12 (not spring boot!).
My repositories are interfaces, extended from spring base Repository interface.

I have implemented many unit tests with in-memory repositories, however in the database (postgreslq) I have some real database functions, which I would like to test. I cannot implement those with JPA queries.

Now I want to test those database functions, so I want to make integration test. However when the application context is initializing, i cannot load the repository interfaces, and receiving

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.company.model.UserRepository' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   exception.

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationContext.class })
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  .. test methods
}
```

The ApplicationContext.class is the real @Configuration class in the project. And it loads the datasource, entitymanagerfactory, transactionmanager, etc. when I execute the test.

```
package com.company.config;

import com.company.service.email.EmailService;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@PropertySources({
  @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
  @PropertySource("file:${CCTNG_HOME}/application.properties")
})
@ComponentScan({"com.company"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContext {

  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIGRATE_USERNAME = "db.migrate.username";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIGRATE_PASSWORD = "db.migrate.password";

  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
//  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_IMPORT_FILES = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files";

  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_URL = "ldap.url";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_USERNAME = "ldap.principal";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_PASSWORD = "ldap.password";

  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_EMAIL_USERNAME = "email.username";
  private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_EMAIL_APPPASSWORD = "email.apppassword";

  @Resource
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
  public Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
//    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
//    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
    flyway.setDataSource(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL), environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIGRATE_USERNAME), 
            environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_MIGRATE_PASSWORD), new String[]{});
    return flyway;
  }

//  @Value("classpath:schema-postgresql.sql")
//  private org.springframework.core.io.Resource schemaScript;
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  @DependsOn("flyway")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

    Properties jpaProterties = new Properties();
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO));
//    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_IMPORT_FILES, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_IMPORT_FILES));

//    jpaProterties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "25");
//    jpaProterties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
//    jpaProterties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates", "true");
//    jpaProterties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProterties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();

    contextSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_URL));
    contextSource.setUserDn(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_USERNAME));
    contextSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LDAP_PASSWORD));

    return contextSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource());
  }

  @Bean(name = "emailService")
  public EmailService email() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mailrelay.xxx.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "10000");

    EmailService email = new EmailService(
            environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_EMAIL_USERNAME),
            environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_EMAIL_APPPASSWORD),
//            environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_EMAIL_APPROOT),
            props);

    return email;

  }
}
```

But for some reason the repositories are not initiated.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Is it the full context? It should contain an `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: Please provide the `ApplicationContext` as part of your question.

Comment: ApplicationContext class is added

Comment: As stated in my comment there is no `@EnableJpaRepositories` hence no support for those interface based repositories. Unless you have another configuration class that contains this and is covered by the component-scan you have no spring data jpa support.

Comment: @M.Deinum. i have JPA support in the normal working of the application. this code specifies the components to scan:     entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

Comment: Which means you are loading additional configuration files/classes which aren't covered by the component scan. JPA support and Spring Data JPA support are different things! YOu need to enable those.

Comment: It makes sense to delete ,y answer, Its not adding any value as such. Also, I am assuming that none of the spring-boot libraries are available in your classpath.

Comment: @M.Denium Ok. i added EnableJpaRepositories to ApplicationContext class, and now the repositores are initiated. thanks!